# Not able to change the file name while writing file into csv and storing into S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, etl, aws-glue

So i have been working on AWS glue and I created an ETL job in pyspark which reads data from data catalog and writes into  and the csv is getting stored in S3 bucket.
But every time the job is running, it is creating different files with different names and i want to override the same file each time the job runs. I am not able to find the correct code for it.
Is there a way override the same file (versioning is enabled in S3).

Below is the  code

```js
import sys
from awsglue.transforms
import *
from awsglue.utils
import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context
import SparkContext
from awsglue.context
import GlueContext
from awsglue.job
import Job


## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

## @type: DataSource## @args: [database = "test_db", table_name = "test_dash_data", transformation_ctx = "datasource0"]## @return: datasource0## @inputs: []
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "test_db", table_name = "test_dash_data", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")

## @type: ApplyMapping## @args: [mapping = [("id", "int", "id", "int"), ("value", "int", "value", "int"), ("email", "string", "email", "string"), ("age", "int", "age", "int")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1"]## @return: applymapping1## @inputs: [frame = datasource0]
applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource0, mappings = [("id", "int", "id", "int"), ("value", "int", "value", "int"), ("email", "string", "email", "string"), ("age", "int", "age", "int")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")

## @type: DataSink## @args: [connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {
  "path": "s3://auroratos3dataimport/customerdata2"
}, format = "csv", transformation_ctx = "datasink2"]
## @return: datasink2
## @inputs: [frame = applymapping1]

repartitioned1 = applymapping1.repartition(1)
datasink2 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = repartitioned1, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {
  "path": "s3://auroratos3dataimport/customerdata2"
}, format = "csv", transformation_ctx = "datasink2")
job.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently AWS Glue doesn't support 'overwrite' mode from pyspark but they are working on this feature.

There is a workaround though, using plain pyspark:

```
repartitioned1.toDF()
  .write
  .mode("overwrite")
  .format("csv")
  .save(s3_path)
```

Comment: Hi Robert, Thanks for your response. Is there a way to rename our file to a particular desired name as well?